# Azure website use python3 with django

Tags: python, django, azure

Officially, Azure Django Websites only support Python 2.7 and Django 1.4, but I am wondering if it is possible to set up an Azure Django website using Python 3.3 and Django 1.6 instead. [This official Azure tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-sites-with-django/) states:

```
Note: Windows Azure web sites now come with Python 2.7 and wfastcgi handler 
pre-installed. However, web frameworks such as Django are not included. You can
still use a different Python interpreter if you prefer. You just need to include
it in the Git repository and configure the web site to use that interpreter
instead of the Python 2.7 interpreter already installed.
```

That sounds to me like you can set it up to use a different Python interpreter, although you may have to also provide your own wfastcgi handler and Django installation if you do this. The tutorial also tells you how to point to the location of the interpreter you want to use.

The Python website provides installers, but how would I get everything needed for the Python interpreter into one folder to put in the git repo? Is everything needed already self-contained in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3`? What about for Django and wfastcgi? Has anyone else tried this?

Answer (score 0):

It is working now: put python-3.4 in runtime.txt at the root of the project.

See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/